# Docker-compose: Why restart does not work with docker-compose run or when there's only one container in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to execute a command using of a docker-compose file, and the code sometimes fails because of connection timeouts. I thought that adding `restart: on-failure` would automatically restart the container if it failed.

The command looks like that

```
docker-compose run --rm \
            -e VAR1=value1 \
            [...] \
            web flask tasks my_failing_task
```

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like that

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    user: root
    image: my-image
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      APPLICATION: "web"
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: "mysecret.json"
    volumes:
      - ../../../stuff/:/stuff/
    restart: on-failure:3
```

I have noticed that the container does not restart when I use `docker-compose run`.

I have then tried to move the command inside the `docker-compose.yml`, like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    user: root
    image: my-image
    network_mode: "host"
    command: flask tasks my_failing_task
    environment:
      APPLICATION: "web"
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: "mysecret.json"
      VAR1: value1
    volumes:
      - ../../../stuff/:/stuff/
    restart: on-failure:3
```

And execute `docker-compose up`, but same result.

It seems that `restart` only works with `docker-compose up` when I add another container, like a redis for example

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    user: root
    image: my-image
    network_mode: "host"
    command: flask tasks my_failing_task
    environment:
      APPLICATION: "web"
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: "mysecret.json"
      VAR1: value1
    volumes:
      - ../../../stuff/:/stuff/
    restart: on-failure:3

  redis:
    hostname: redis
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Then it actually restarts up to 3 times if fails.

So my questions are:

- Why doesn't `restart` work with `run`
- Why does `restart` only work with `up` IF there are more than 1 container in the `docker-compose.yml` file

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the code, [`docker-compose run` always implies `restart: no`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/8f2bb66e733d9204050fcee57e03022cbb135e52/compose/cli/main.py#L1375).  The GitHub issue [docker/compose#6302](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6302) describes this a little bit further.

`docker-compose run` is used to run a "one-off" container, running a single alternate command with mostly the same specification as what's described in `docker-compose.yml`.  Imagine Compose didn't have this override.  If you did `docker-compose run` a command that failed, it would restart, potentially forever.  If it ran in the background, you'd leak a restarting container; if it ran in the foreground, you'd have to go to another terminal to kill off the container.  That's a harsh penalty for typing `docker-compose run web bsah` by accident.

Otherwise, most of the options, including `restart:`, get passed through directly to the Docker API.  It shouldn't make a difference running `docker-compose up` if there's only one container or multiple.